# rails stripping / inside an SVG image tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, svg

Using Rails 6 / Ruby 6:

I'm trying to insert an image path into an SVG image tag but somehow the path slashes are getting stripped out.

```
<% imgpath = asset_path(challenge.imgname) %>
<%= logger.debug "Asset: " + imgpath %>
```

Outputs the expected:
`Asset: /assets/shower.jpg`

But inside my SVG image tag:

```
<image "<%= asset_path challenge.imgname %>" height="100%" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" />
```

(and upon "Inspecting" in Chrome)
It shows up as:

```html
<image " assets shower.jpg " height="100%" width="100%" 
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"></image>
```

Using `raw` does not seem to change this behaviour.

Mysteriously "view source" in Chrome does actually show the path:

```html
<image "/assets/greencommute.jpg" height="100%" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" />
```

But regardless the image does not render.

Any clues about what's going on?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`image` tag requires `href` attribute:

```
<image href="<%= asset_path challenge.imgname %>" height="100%" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" />
```

in your current code rendered url is parsed by browser as an attribute name (and not only browser - note the code highlight color)

Comment: Thanks Vasfed - I knew it had to be something stupid; and there it was! I lost the href when I went from static to dynamic content.